# Replacing UL content on click of two tabs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two tabs, one is named **Default** and the other **Dim** as you can see I have the `sample` var with the content I need to show when user clicks **Dim** but how do I go about replacing the content that loads initially when user clicks back to **Default** tab? How do I hold that state so I can just use `.replaceWith()` again? Thanks!

```
var sample = `<ul class="WAC-LIGHTING-FEATURE-LIST id="dim-feature-list">
                        <li>Delivered Lumens: 980lm</li>
                        <li>Construction: Die-cast aluminum trim</li>
                        <li>Adjustable LED light engine included with housing: Vertical Adjustment 0-30°, Horizontal Adjustment 365°</li>
                        <li>Spot, Narrow Flood, and Flood optics included with housing</li>
                        <li>2700K, 3000K, 3500K, or 4000K CRI 90 Color Temperature options available with housing LED light engine</li>
                        <li>Refer to specification sheet for lumens and CBCP data</li>
                        <li> 50/60Hz</li>
                    </ul>`;


$('#dim').click(function() {
    $('#default-wac-feature-list').replaceWith(sample);
    $(this).addClass("tab-active");
if ($(this).attr("class", "tab-active")) {
        $("#default-wac-feature-list").hide();
} else {
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- `replaceWith()`?? I think `.html()` will be easier .. see the next example
- Use `.hasClass()` to check for classes instead of using `.attr('class'...`

```js
var sample = `<ul class="WAC-LIGHTING-FEATURE-LIST" id="dim-feature-list">
    <li>Delivered Lumens: 980lm</li>
    <li>Construction: Die-cast aluminum trim</li>
    <li>Adjustable LED light engine included with housing: Vertical Adjustment 0-30°, Horizontal Adjustment 365°</li>
    <li>Spot, Narrow Flood, and Flood optics included with housing</li>
    <li>2700K, 3000K, 3500K, or 4000K CRI 90 Color Temperature options available with housing LED light engine</li>
    <li>Refer to specification sheet for lumens and CBCP data</li>
    <li> 50/60Hz</li>
</ul>`;

var Intial_value = '';
$('#dim').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if(!$this.hasClass('tab-active')){
    Intial_value = $('#default-wac-feature-list').html();
    $('#default-wac-feature-list').html(sample);
    $('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
    $this.addClass('tab-active');
  }
});
$('#default').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if(!$this.hasClass('tab-active')){
    $('#default-wac-feature-list').html(Intial_value);
    $('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
    $this.addClass('tab-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.tab-active{
  background : #555;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="default" class="tab-active">Default</button>
<button id="dim">Dim</button>

<div id="default-wac-feature-list">The Default Text</div>
```

Comment: Looks good but when I click "Dim" button twice it stops working??

Comment: @rec0nstr Answer updated .. the problem was in the `tab-active` class you need to remove it from other tabs then add it to the clicked one